# Error found while loading /etc/profile: /etc/profile.d/01-locale-fix.sh: line 2: /usr/bin/locale-check: No such file or directory

Tags: 20.04, etc

I'm a newbie, 3 months into Ubuntu, running 20.04 from 18.04 and 19.10.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reinstall single package which contains [missed binary](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=focal&section=all&arch=any&keywords=locale-check&searchon=contents).

Open terminal and execute:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall base-files
```

Answer (score 0):

If still fails, try these commands:

```
$ sudo apt-cache madison base-files
base-files | 11ubuntu5.2 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
base-files |  11ubuntu5 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
base-files |  11ubuntu5 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main Sources
base-files | 11ubuntu5.2 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main Sources
```

and then:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall base-files=11ubuntu5.2
```